# What do these parameters mean at the beginning of my SQL Server query plan?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm looking at query plan in SQL Server Mgmt Studio and I see something like this:

```
(@P0 nvarchar(4000), @P1 nvarchar(4000)) Update...
```

What does the type mean beside the parameters? For this example lets assume that the column for those parameters are actually `varchar(64)`. Is this how the parameters are being bound at runtime?

EDIT

This is a Java EE application using JDBC 3.0 or 4.0 providers. Basically we have a properties file full of SQL statements like this:

```
mySqlStatementFoo = UPDATE Schema.Table.Column set column = 1 WHERE objectID = ?
```

It looks like in the past if there was a binding mismatch we would cast the param like so:

```
Where objectID = CAST(? AS VARCHAR(36))
```

I suppose they chose to do it this way since we support multiple databases. I.E. DB2 and Oracle. I haven't seen the actual Java, but I suspect they are just selecting the statement from the file and sending it down the wire. I'm doing load testing and seeing that we are doing table scans and suspect that the optimizer isn't using the correct index because the parameters are being bound incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server made a guess at the data type based on the format of the submitted statement. Not sure where this `UPDATE` statement originated, but you should consider using stored procedures or strongly typed parameterized statements.

Comment: How can I strongly type the statement? I see this parameter binding problem came up before and the developers added a cast to the param in the where clause.

Comment: Well, for one, you could use a stored procedure. Otherwise you're going to have to share more info. What developers? What language are they writing their code in? What provider are they using to connect to SQL Server? Show some code and we may be able to help/

Comment: I've added some context above.

Comment: Yes, you are probably seeing implicit conversions in the plan, and this can often negate the use of an index. Can I suggest stored procedures one more time/

Comment: If only it were up to me, but its not. I'll pass along the suggestion. Otherwise, it looks like we will be writing a lot of cast statements I suppose. Add your answer below to the original question and I'll accept it.

Comment: Where exactly did you get the query plan? Can you share it? What is the parameterization setting of the database, simple or forced? If stored procedures are not possible, is it possible to extend the query with SQL Server-specific syntax?

Comment: The query plan was generated from management studio. I was able to prevent the scan by casting to varchar. I don't think I can share the query plan publicly though. The queries themselves are generated during application deployment and is based on the database target. So yes it is possible to change the syntax of the statements based on database. These cast statements for example will not show up in the Oracle or DB2 statements.

Comment: `The query plan was generated from management studio.` <-- using what query text, exactly? (Feel free to swap out table names etc. but `WHERE objectid = ?` would not work as is in SSMS, so I'm wondering if you're really seeing the same plan the application gets.)

Comment: basically I have a query that generates a list of queries using a lot of CPU time. One of the columns is query plan which I get from:

`sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle).query_plan`

The column will be a hyperlink to some xml that mgmt studio uses to build the query plan

Comment: Also the original symptom (High CPU) goes away when I cast the params.

Comment: Another approach you might try, which makes the statement itself a little less goofy: `DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(36) = ?; UPDATE...WHERE col = @p1;`

Comment: http://dbareactions.com/post/45837752405/when-the-developers-hear-me-suggest-switching-to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are likely seeing implicit conversions due to the guesses SQL Server has to make. It is creating a plan that will work not just for the parameter value you're passing now, but other potential values, too. With strings it (or perhaps JDBC? not sure) chooses an arbitrary default of 4000 and Unicode. I believe there are ways in JDBC to *not* send Unicode ([Unicode vs. non-Unicode implicit conversions are among the most tedious](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/implicit-conversion-costs)), but you're still going to deal with the length issue (which may or may not be an issue in your specific case; again, not sure).

To avoid the implicit conversions and guesses, and ultimately the scans and high CPU conditions, you need to make SQL Server understand the data type that is being used in the parameter through explicit / strong typing.

Here are my suggestions, in order of preference:

1. Switch to stored procedures.
2. Switch to stored procedures.
3. Declare your variables explicitly, e.g.:

   ```
   DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(36) = ?; UPDATE ... WHERE col = @p1;
   ```
4. Keep using `CAST`/`CONVERT`.

Comment: Are suggestions 1 and 2 deliberately the same?

Comment: @Martin yes, they are.

Comment: @MartinSmith http://www.diggingforfire.net/fightclub/ ;-)